# Paragraph space

Tags: theorems, paragraphs

I'm currently writing a math document containing equations, theorems, remarks, etc. I find it difficult to understand how LaTeX manages the vertical space between two paragraphs. E.g. when you don't specify anything about the paragraph style, a new paragraph is indented but there is no vertical space between the two paragraphs. Before and after a theorem, there is a line skip. I would like to have a vertical space between two paragraphs too but when I put `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` in the preamble, it messes up the space before and after a theorem.

How does one manage the space between two paragraphs? Should one use two `enters`, `\\` or `\par` to make a new paragraph? What's the difference between those? And is there a difference between `\[ \]`, `equation*` and `align*` with respect to the paragraph space?

Comment: You could also use `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip`. It all depends what you want to achieve with those spaces. Also you could use the variant `\\[<length>]`. If you don't like the indent, you could use `\noindent` before the paragraph or `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in your preamble.

Comment: If you're adjusting the space between paragraphs, you should probably also adjust the space before/after the theorem to suit your needs.

Comment: Here is a link to the spaces between equations and the like: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71198/10898 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30909/10898

Answer (score 4):

If a document indents the first line of a paragraph (in TeX jargon, the indentation amount is governed by the `\parindent` length parameter), one usually does *not* provide extra vertical space between *ordinary* paragraphs, i.e., the length of the `\parskip` parameter is `0pt` by default.

Conversely, some - but certainly not all - document styles that set `\parindent` to zero also set a non-zero amount of `\parskip`. Otherwise, situations can easily arise where the reader wouldn't be sure if a parapraph break is present or not.

In TeX and LaTeX, a paragraph break is generated automatically whenever one or more entirely-blank lines in the input file are encountered. It is considered bad form to generate line breaks through `\\` instructions (and unpleasant things *can* happen if you do it anyway).

Somewhat different considerations apply for "out-of-the-ordinary" paragraphs, such as theorems. There, one generally does want to generate some visual separation from the surrounding, ordinary-text paragraphs. Just how much extra vertical space is inserted above and below the theorem depends on whether you've loaded certain theorem-related packages such as `ntheorem` or `amsthm`; the latter is loaded automatically if you use a document class such as `amsart`.

Coming to your final question, there are indeed differences, in terms of the vertical space above display-math material, depending on whether `\[ ... \]`, `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` or one of the `amsmath` multiline equation environments such as `align` and `gather` are used. For more information on this subject see, e.g., the postings [abovedisplayskip vs abovedisplayshortskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30909/5001) and [Un-indent all paragraphs and increase the space between paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67829/5001).